# IntelliJ not recognising changes on my Java project

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, bitbucket

When I try to commit and push my code to BitBucket/Github (from IntelliJ), it commits and pushes just the .xml files, but not the actual Java code I am writing. After I made commit and push, I am adding changes to the code (in the same class), I am trying to commit again but it pops up a window Nothing to Commit, with a message: No Changes Detected.

Why does IntelliJ not see my .java files?

Comment: Are your java files part of a folder in the .gitignore file?

Comment: @f1sh I'm sorry, I'm new to Version Control and I don't know how to tell if my java files are in the .gitignore. I guess they're not... This is what I have there: ### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

Comment: Did you add the files to the commit? I'm unfamiliar with IntelliJ's git GUI, so adding them may be irrelevant. Could you open up a terminal and run a "git status" in that directory? It's important to tell if this is a problem with how you have git set up or if it's something with IntelliJ's GUI.

Comment: @Cassara where is the `.git` directory located? Is it in the project root? Do you have the source files below the `.git` directory?

Comment: IntelliJ does not show me the changed files at all when I try to make a commit. It only shows me the .xml files, not my Java classes. How can I add them manually, so I can later commit them? I tried git status in the CMD and it shows that there are Untracked files

Comment: @CrazyCoder The directory is in the project root, I don't have the source files there

Comment: @Cassara please attach the screenshot of the file manager or IntelliJ IDEA project view showing where you have the source files and where the `.git` directory is.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I just realised that I had messed up with my project folder (I had actually 2 different folders set up and was using the incorrect one). I had .idea in one of it (and thought that was the correct one), but all my source files were in the other folder. Silly, beginner mistake, I know... But I fixed it now, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA version control integration works with the roots you've configured in the [VCS Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-version-control.html#associate_directory_with_VCS).

By default the project root is the same as the VCS root.

If your source files are located elsewhere, you need to add more VCS roots in the IDE settings.

Double check you have the correct project open which contains the files you change and the VCS roots in the IDE include the content roots for the modules you are working with.